# Drools session share the same working memory?

Tags: drools, rule-engine, business-rules

When application creates multiple state-full kie session, do they share same working memory or they have separate working memory. So if a fact is inserted in one session , will it be available in another session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `KieSession` **IS** the working memory. You can create multiple, independent `KieSessions` from a single `KieBase`, but if you want to broadcast facts to multiple session you will need to implement that mechanism yourself.

Hope it helps,

Comment: My application creates multiple sessions in asynchronous fashion. Each session has two category of rules that get fired . In first set of rules all the required object from DB  are loaded into the working memory, second set of rules uses the objects loaded in previous set of rules as condition.

Comment: So session 0  rule (second set of rules) makes a db call to save the object in DB.  Before the object get saved in DB, session 1 rules(first set of rules) get triggered and since object is not saved in DB, it doesn't insert the fact in working memory of session 1. Hence session 1 rule(second set of rule), again saves the same set of data (which is already inserted by session 0 rule)

Comment: also the process of saving data in DB from rule is asynchronous. It just sends data to db service queue and doesn't wait for any response.